# Working around Android SDK bug: Handler.getLooper() clears thread interruption status

Tags: java, android, interrupt

I spent hours tracing down the cause of my code losing thread interruption status, only to find it's actually caused by a bug in the Android SDK! Take a look at the `Looper.getLooper()` method:

```java
    /**
     * This method returns the Looper associated with this thread. If this thread not been started
     * or for any reason isAlive() returns false, this method will return null. If this thread
     * has been started, this method will block until the looper has been initialized.  
     * @return The looper.
     */
    public Looper getLooper() {
        if (!isAlive()) {
            return null;
        }

        // If the thread has been started, wait until the looper has been created.
        synchronized (this) {
            while (isAlive() && mLooper == null) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return mLooper;
    }
```

Notice that it eats an `InterruptedException` without re-interrupting!

So, now that I know it's not a problem with my code, what's the best way to work around this? Should I store my thread's interruption status to a flag before calling `.getLooper()`, and then after that call, interrupt myself if the flag is set? Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The method is public
you can create your own Handler by extending from this one, and override the method to get it to do what you want, without calling the super

```
 public class BetterHandler extends Handler {
   @Override
   public Looper getLooper(){ 
        if (!isAlive()) {
        return null;
    }

    // If the thread has been started, wait until the looper has been created.
    synchronized (this) {
        while (isAlive() && mLooper == null) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               throw e
            }
        }
    }
    return mLooper;
   }

 }
```

And use the new handler wherever you need.
Obviously you can't replace the handler class for those who use it outside of your code.

Comment: *Facepalm* oh duh! Why didn't I think of that? I'll try this shortly :)

Comment: Ok so I tried this and firstly, the problem is in `HandlerThread`, not `Handler`. But besides that, for some reason when I tried to override the method, the compiler claimed that it couldn't access `mLooper` (nor any other variables from the super class). So what I ended up doing was duplicating the class entirely (it's just a thin wrapper over `Thread` after all) and editing the method in my copy. I will probably make a PR to AOSP to address this :)